# Finding and selecting best publisher by number of books

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I have homework assignment, which requires to output one or more publishers, which's the most unique books are borrowed at the library. Sorry if it's hard to understand.

I tried following query:

```
SELECT Book.Publisher, COUNT(DISTINCT Book.Title)
FROM Book, LibraryInventory
WHERE LibraryInventory.BorrowedBy IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Book.Publisher
```

It shows all publishers and how many unique books are borrowed, however assignment requires only best publisher(s).

Any suggestions how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework, I can give you a tip.
a. Find what "best publisher" means. You should end up with a query that shows the count of books borrowed and nothing more, e.g. the number 42.
b. Find which publisher have 42 books borrowed.
c. Now try to combine the two.

Comment: That seems to work. In pseudocode:
SELECT Publisher
FROM
( publisher | count ) AS Result1,
( count ) AS Result2
HAVING Result1.count = MAX(Result2.count).
However since I already have that number in Result1, isn't there a way to get it, without using Result2?

Comment: @EdgarasPavlišinas: You might want to study derived tables, window functions, and CTEs.

Comment: @EdgarasPavlišinas: tip2: nested queries